# Bluetooth crahes on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, headset

Since installing ubuntu 12.10 my bluetooth is acting up.

as soon as I try to pair, the bluetooth applet crashes or the whole
system freezes..

under 12.04 and 12.04.1 I had no problems whatsoever. Both my HTC desire HD and Jabra Supreme headset would effortlessly pair with my HP ProBook 4720s.

How do I make bluetooth work?

Regards,
Botak

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just now when I was trying to pair my lenovo z570 with my nokia bh503 headset.
I found it impossible with the default manager, but then I installed `blueman`. You can do that via the terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

or via the Software-Center: [image: Install via the software center]

With that installed I ran `bluetooth manager` from the applications list, using that manager I was able to pair my devices with no major problem (took some moments though)
I hope it solves your problem too. Best luck to you!

Comment: Didn't worked for me... blueman was also unable to detect any devices.